# How do i solve the security problems caused by pg_cron?

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, dockerfile

I am using pg_cron to schedule a task which should be repeated every 1 hour.
I have installed and using this inside a docker environment inside the postgres container.
And I am calling the query to create this job using python from a different container.

I can see that job is created successfully but is not being executed due to lack of permission since the pg_hba.conf is not set to trust or due to no .pgpass file.

But if I enable any of those both, anyone can enter into database by using docker exec and do psql in the container.

Is there anyway to avoid this security issue??? Since in production environment it should not be allowed for anyone to enter into the database without a password.

Answer (score 0):

Either keep people from running `docker exec` on the container or use something else than `pg_cron`.

I would feel nervous if random people were allowed to run `docker exec` on the container with my database or my job scheduler in it.